# data not getting inserted into table even though successful message is being displayed

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

here i,m trying to enter data into table playlist using information extracted from other tables.
after executing it,i'm getting the "succesfull" message but data is not actually inserted..
can anyone point out the mistake?

```
 <?php

$connect= mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die('couldnt connect to database');

mysql_select_db("music") or die("couldn't find the database");

        $regis['id']=$_GET['id'];
        $regis['username']=$_GET['username'];

           $query="SELECT * FROM songs WHERE id ='id'";
                       $quer="SELECT * FROM images WHERE id ='id'";
            $q="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='username'";




           $query=mysql_query($query);
          $quer=mysql_query($quer);

            $q=mysql_query($q);



           $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

          $regis['id']=$row['id'];
           $regis['title']=$row['title'];

          $regis['artist']=$row['artist'];

        $rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
         $regis['link']=$rows['link'];


      $r=mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
         $regis['uid']=$r['uid'];


        $sql="insert into playlist (songid,song,image,album,uid) values('{$regis['id']}','{$regis['title']}','{$regis['link']}','{$regis['artist']}','{$regis['uid']}')";
        $res=mysql_query($sql);
        if($res)
        {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
            echo 'alert("addition to your playlist was succesful")';
            echo "</script>";

            }
        else
        {   
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
            echo 'alert("'.mysql_error().'Please try again")';
            echo "</script>";
        }
```

?>

Comment: sorry for indentation problem.

Comment: Go Go Nugget "don't use the `mysql_` functions" comment!

Comment: @vodich i enforced this condition and now the message is"please try again" do know how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){
  //query inserted at least one row in db
}
```